# Solr How to make eDisMax query with proximity search and wildcards?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm trying to use the eDisMax query parser to get wildcard results on a phrase but it doesn't seem to work.

```
field:value           comment:...text... The best movie ever! ...text...
```

The only query field is comment.

The query `query: "\" best movie \""` <= this returns results!

The query `query: "\" best mov* \""` <= this doesn't return results.

**How can I query with proximity and wildcards?**

I've also tried using the standard query parser but it didn't support proximity+wildcards. I've seen some other answers wich recommend installing a patch but I would like to keep the standard Solr build.

I'm using SolrJ and Solr 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

By using the solution mentioned here ([SOLR-1604](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1604)) you can add wildcard into phrase queries.

Comment: I know but then I have to rebuild solr :S

Comment: Are you sure it's a stable patch? have you used it?

Comment: No I didn't use it by myself but i saw the discussion on the mail group that helped others.

Answer (score 0):

I am using solr 6.0. In the solr UI I choose the edismax search, in the q field i write "best move*" and i set the qf. it returns the proper output.

Comment: What version of Solr are you using? Are you using edismax? I'm currently on 5.3 and it doesn't seem to work.